# find protocol corresponding to URI in Java

Tags: java, url, uri, inputstream

I have URI object in Java. I want to convert it to InputStream, but the conversion should depend on the protocol. I can make it this way if my URI is `http://somepath.com/mysuperfile.xsl`:

```
return myURI.toURL().openConnection().getInputStream();
```

or this way if my uri is `file:///somepath/mysuperfile.xsl`:

```
return new FileInputStream(Paths.get(myURI).toFile());
```

or maybe even some another way. I can try to check it manually, but do Java have some nice/proper way to check it, maybe using that new `java.nio.*` package?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Every URI is defined as consisting of four parts, as follows:
>
> `[scheme name] : [hierarchical part] [[ ? query ]] [[ # fragment ]]`

If the thing you want is the scheme name (which roughly translates to protocol), just use

```
switch ( myURI.getScheme() ) {
  case "http":
    return myURI.toURL().openConnection().getInputStream();
  case "ftp":
    // do something   
  case "file":
    return new FileInputStream( Paths.get(myURI).toFile() );
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#getScheme%28%29

**or**, if you just want to generate an `InputStream` *without* differentiating the scheme, simply use

```
return myURI.toURL().openStream();
```

or

```
return myURI.toURL().openConnection().getInputStream();
```

(as you already did for HTTP protocol/scheme)

Comment: There is no need to special case schemes. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19430840/166339) for details.

Comment: There ARE situations where scheme cases are necessary. See my comments to your answer for details.

Comment: The question isn't asking about any of those situations. The posted code suggests the task at hand is reading a file. The OP may be under the impression that different protocols require different handling, but that isn't the case. Java provides an API that successfully abstracts that away.

Comment: Firstly, I'm not into 'impressions', because I'm a programmer, not an impressionist. I'm not into 'suggestions' either because of *per analogiam* reasons. If OP knows what he's asking, he got an answer. Period. If he doesn't, he has first to admit it; I won't assume that out of thin air. If there's a question asked, I answer. Ockham's razor is a good idea, but respect for questions of original poster is even better IMO. And - if Java's API abstraction was successful, would there be a bug report for this particular ('file' scheme use) case?

Comment: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4485313 http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4191800

yeah, they got "bug won't fix" for security reasons. Does this prove the abstraction is successful or rather that it is inherently flawed but within acceptable range? "Not supporting it for files
makes it impossible to use a URL transparently for
storing data which might be on a web server, FTP
server, or in the local filesystem." - that's not my opinion, but yeah, it's quite accurate IMHO. No transparency in using object == failed abstraction

Answer (score 1):

No need to special case file URIs. The same code works for either case. I just tested it with the following little scratch program:

### URIReadTest.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class URIReadTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URI uri = new URI("file:///tmp/test.txt");
        InputStream in = uri.toURL().openConnection().getInputStream();
        // or, more concisely:
        // InputStream in = uri.toURL().openStream();
        int b;
        while((b = in.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char) b);
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Make a `/tmp/test.txt` on your system and you'll see the contents of it printed out when you compile and run the above code.

Comment: Sometimes you need to differentiate the action based on the URI/URL scheme. That was exactly what OP asked about. "I what to convert it to InputStream. But conversion depends from the protocol." That is HIS requirement, not MINE idea. If it depends on the protocol, you need to introduce differentiation of code branches. You want to say this *won't ever happen*? Well, it does.

Comment: One situation, only partially related (but still) to this question, when it is important, is when you want to actually WRITE to a file. Ever tried to write to a file:// stream from openConnection()? "Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownServiceException: protocol doesn't support output" - that's the case when I done scheme differentiation in my own code. It works like a charm; you *can* write to ftp & http schemes, but to write to file you actually have to open it as a File, not file:/// - there's even a bug on Oracle about it, but it's by design (security) AFAIR

Comment: @vaxquis: My interpretation of the question was different than yours. All the OP wants to do is read from the URL. The OP is apparently under the impression that special handling is needed to process file URIs. But that isn't the case. As for your other comment, `openConnection()` returns an `InputStream` which you can't write to ever, no matter what the scheme is. In any case, the question mentions nothing about writing, only reading.

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong, because obviously you aren't; it's just that as long as OP won't comment on his needs, I'm sticking to the most conservative interpretation possible. If somebody asks for a hamburger, I won't go and give him a fish; I know 'burgers might be bad for his health, but it's *his* call, not *mine*. "I can try to check it maually, but do Java have some nice/proper way to check it?" That is his question, so that is my answer. I'm not a psychic, he asked for XYZZY, he got XYZZY.

Answer (score -1):

you can check the characters at the start of the string with the startsWith(String prefix) function, it is www. or http:// use the first method otherwise use the second method.

Comment: ... only there ain't no String to begin with. You'd have to myURI.toString() first, which is (roughly) what the system call to myURI.getScheme() does anyway.